# Error in dateFormat returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, nsdate

As an exercise to practice Objective-C, I am converting Swift code to Objective-C. After 1.5k lines converted, I find myself blocked for the past few days on one last issue.

In a few cells of my TableViewController, the description labels don't appear at all. I checked my code, and it seems the strings that are passed to the cells are actually empty or nil.

I seem to have made a syntax error in converting the Swift code that returns the date to my cells. What error have I made that makes the date nil?

## THE CODE:

#### ViewController.m

...

```
NSDate const *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

self.sections =  [[NSMutableArray<NSString *> alloc]init];
self.items = [[NSMutableArray<NSMutableArray<TableItem *> *> alloc]init];
self.sectionItems = [[NSMutableArray<TableItem *> alloc]init];
```

...

This is the cell data that doesn't load correctly (empty strings are passed to `theDescription`):

```
anItem = [[TableItem alloc ]initWithTitle: @"Custom: dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss" theDescription: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [now toString: [DateFormat CustomDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"]]]];
        [_sectionItems addObject: anItem];

//theDescription should be: @"25 April 2016 15:04:57" after this ^, but is actually nil or @""

anItem = [[TableItem alloc ]initWithTitle: @"ISO8601(Year)" theDescription: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [now toString: [DateFormat ISODateFormat: ISOFormatYear]]]];
        [_sectionItems addObject: anItem];

//theDescription should be: @"2016" after this ^, but is actually nil or @""
```

Here's where I think I've made a mistake:

Original Swift syntax:

#### Extension.swift

toString() function

```
 case .ISO8601(let isoFormat):
        dateFormat = (isoFormat != nil) ? isoFormat!.rawValue : ISO8601Format.DateTimeMilliSec.rawValue
        zone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
```

What I tried:

#### Extension.m

```
else if([format.dateFormatType compare: ISO8601DateFormatType] == NSOrderedSame) {
    NSString *isoFormat = ISO8601DateFormatType;
    dateFormat =  (isoFormat != nil) ? isoFormat : ISOFormatDateTimeMilliSec;
    zone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
}
```

Comment: I have not looked at your whole code, but I suspect your description labels to be present but with empty strings. Check that the strings you are setting as your description labels are not empty or null.

Comment: You are correct: they are empty. I need to figure out why that is. Hence my question here. I have been looking it over but I can't seem to find what's wrong.

Comment: What is this `now` variable ?

Comment: it could be something simple like the cells being created before the data has been created and passed to them. I'm not fluent enough in obj-c to tell from your code but thats one of the first things I check when it comes to tableViews.

Comment: I am fluent in Obj-C but is is pretty hard to go through the code because you are using empty parameter names for methods. I am also not absolutely sure that the bug is in the posted code. It should be easy to find the problem with logging, debugger or unit tests.

Comment: Hahahaha, you are right ! The thing is: those cells actually are the unit tests of the code. Debugger gives me nothing :/

Comment: Logging helped me find that empty strings were generated.

Comment: What should I do to make my question clearer ?

Comment: Wow that is a lot of code.  Can you please cut down your question or attached a sample project that provides a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?  Maybe abstract your `toString` code into a new project, and provide test cases of what is expected, what the output actually is, and how they differ.

Comment: @JAL Question edited ! I hope it is now clearer.

Comment: @Sulthan Question edited ! I hope it is now clearer.

Comment: @JAL I think I was somewhat able to isolate the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849392/how-to-convert-this-swift-syntax-to-objective-c

Comment: Looks like your other question was closed.  See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDate formatter : dateFormat : [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] : [NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

`dateFormat` is `@"Custom"`, as it was set here:

```
else if([format.dateFormatType compare: CustomDateFormatType] == NSOrderedSame) {
    NSString *string = CustomDateFormatType;
    dateFormat = string;
}
```

This is passed into your `NSDateFormatter` constructor here:

```
formatter.dateFormat = format;
```

`@"Custom"` is not a valid date format string.  Instead, pass in `format.formatDetails`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDate formatter : format.formatDetails : [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] : [NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

I should note that not using named arguments in Objective-C makes your code much harder to read.

Comment: As for named parameters, I will immediately start converting all func parameters to named paramters !

Comment: I also upvoted your answer ! I can't say it enough, thank you !

Comment: No worries, happy to help!  Don't forget to come back and award the bounty.  Happy coding!