# How do I convert a parameterised enum/ enum with associated values from Swift to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, enums, nsdate

**NOTE:** As an exercise, I am converting Swift code to Objective-C.

---

**CODE:** Original Swift code from which I converted:

```
case .ISO8601(let isoFormat):
    let dateFormat = (isoFormat != nil) ? isoFormat! : ISO8601Format(dateString: string as String)
    let formatter = NSDate.formatter(format: dateFormat.rawValue)
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat.rawValue
    if let date = formatter.dateFromString(string as String) {
        self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:date)
    } else {
        self.init()
    }
```

---

**WHAT I TRIED:** The Objective-C conversion I tried:

```
else if([format.dateFormatType compare: ISO8601DateFormatType] == NSOrderedSame) {
    NSString *isoFormat = // WHAT DO TO HERE ?;
    NSString *dateFormat = (isoFormat != nil) ? isoFormat : ISO8601DateFormatType;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDate formatterWithFormat: dateFormat andTimeZone: [NSTimeZone localTimeZone ] andLocale: [NSLocale currentLocale]];
    formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier: (@"en_US_POSIX")];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dateFormat]);
    // dateFormat = ISO8601
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:(string)];

    //
    // ISSUE IS HERRRREEEE ^
    //

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date]);
    // date = nil

    if (date != nil){
        return [self initWithTimeInterval: 0 sinceDate: date];
    }
    else {
        return [self init];
    }
}
```

The approach I took was to use a separate class to reproduce the behaviour of a swift enum with associated values (this was a originally a large swift enum with associated values):

**DateFormat.m**

```
#import "DateFormat.h"

@implementation DateFormat

NSString * const ISO8601DateFormatType = @"ISO8601";
NSString * const DotNetDateFormatType = @"DotNet";
NSString * const RSSDateFormatType = @"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ";
NSString * const AltRSSDateFormatType = @"d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ";
NSString * const CustomDateFormatType = @"Custom";

NSString * const ISOFormatYear = @"yyyy";
NSString * const ISOFormatYearMonth = @"yyyy-MM"; // 1997-07
NSString * const ISOFormatDate = @"yyyy-MM-dd"; // 1997-07-16
NSString * const ISOFormatDateTime = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ"; // 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
NSString * const ISOFormatDateTimeSec = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"; // 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
NSString * const ISOFormatDateTimeMilliSec = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"; // 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00

- (instancetype) initWithType: (NSString *) formatType details: (NSString *) details {

    if(self = [super init]) {
        _dateFormatType = formatType;
        _formatDetails = details;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (instancetype) ISODateFormat: (NSString *) isoFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: ISO8601DateFormatType details: isoFormat];
}

+ (instancetype) DotNetDateFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: DotNetDateFormatType details: nil];
}

+ (instancetype) RSSDateFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: RSSDateFormatType details: nil];
}

+ (instancetype) AltRSSDateFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: AltRSSDateFormatType details: nil];
}

+ (instancetype) CustomDateFormat: (NSString *) formatString
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: CustomDateFormatType details: formatString];
}

@end
```

---

**MY ISSUE:**

In my code, `dateFromString` returns `nil` because the format passed as a parameter is incorrect. The reason that happens is because of the way I converted the enum with associated value line: `case .ISO8601(let isoFormat):`

I don't know how to convert `case .ISO8601(let isoFormat):` into Objective-C.

The issue is that enums with associated values only exist in Swift, not in Objective-C.

So how can I convert that enum with associated value line case `.ISO8601(let isoFormat):` in Objective-C ?

---

**SOLUTION:**

EDIT: The answer was simple, I just had to write: `NSString *isoFormat = format.formatDetails;`in the Objective-C conversion I showed at the beginning of the question. (Check my Class DateFormat implementation file to understand)

Comment: Isn't this a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753954/description-label-doesnt-appear-in-my-tableviewcontroller-cells ? We won't be able to help you until you write [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No, nothing to do with it. That one was answered by JAL !

Comment: This is another issue. But the DateFormat Class is used everywhere, so that's why you see some code again.

Comment: @Sulthan I edited my question! I hope it is now better and clearer !

Comment: @rmaddy I edited my question! I hope it is now better and clearer !

Comment: @JAL I edited my question! I hope it is now better and clearer !

Comment: @JohnCaswell I edited my question! I hope it is now better and clearer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain your code for you:

```
NSString *isoFormat = ISO8601DateFormatType;
```

(assigns string `ISO8601` to `isoFormat`)

```
NSString *dateFormat = (isoFormat != nil) ? isoFormat : ISO8601DateFormatType;
```

(`isoFormat` is never `nil` so the condition is always true. If it were false, we would again assign string `ISO8601`).

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = ...
```

(we get some formatter, it doesn't matter how because we are overwriting all its important properties anyway)

```
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier: (@"en_US_POSIX")];
```

(let's overwrite the `[NSLocale currentLocale]` above with POSIX locale, that's fine)

```
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

(let's set time zone again)

```
formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat;
```

(let's set string `ISO8601` to be the date format, this is not a valid date format)

```
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:(string)];
```

(let's try to parse a date using an invalid date format `ISO8601`. Obviously, this will return `nil`)

In short - the problem is exactly the same as the problem in your previous question [Error in dateFormat returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753954/description-label-doesnt-appear-in-my-tableviewcontroller-cells)

Comment: @Coder1000 Assign a correct date format to you `formatter`. If you want a better answer, you will have to ask a better question first.

Comment: my question basically boils down to : how to convert `case .ISO8601(let isoFormat):` ?

Comment: @Coder1000 It's hard to know without knowing your implementation but maybe you want to use `NSString *isoFormat = format.formatDetails;` ?